# extract string between two keywords spanning multiple lines using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have been trying to parse typescript files to extract imports from a typescript component file using nodejs, but got stuck at the point where the imports are listed on multiple lines. for e.g.

```
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ClassA,
  ClassB,
  ClassC,
} from '@api/module/module-name/module-name.actions';
import { AbstractControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
```

if you see above, I need to identify @api/*.actions and extract imports from this, i.e. ClassA, ClassB and ClassC.

I was thinking of reading the ts file, remove all new line characters between `import` and `;` and then extract the comma separated list between the `{}`

Any suggestions on how to do this in a better way?